# Can we use division algorithm here? $a = 17$ and $b = −3$

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, discrete-mathematics

But I think is that we can use it where reminder is $2$ and quotient is $-5$. But I am confused about quotient is this ok for quotient to be a negative number?  We are finding $\space b \mid a \space$ here!!!

Comment: Is it okay for a quotient to be a negative number?  What is 10 divided by -2?

Comment: 10/-2 is -5. But the problem is with division algorithm. I think we can't express this notation there!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's completely okay if the quotient is negative .
What actually are we doing here ? . By Division Algorithm we have the equation :- $$a = bq + r$$ where $ 0 \le r < |b|$ , and we know $a$ is the dividend , $b$ is the divisor , $q$ is the quotient and $r$ is the remainder . When we have $b$ is negative and $a$ is positive , then $q$ can surely be negative . Just keep in mind that $r$ is always positive .

Comment: You are correct that in mathematics, the remainder $r$ is defined to always be non-negative. Many computer programming languages make a different choice. The language designers find it more important to have $-(a/b)=(-a)/b$ for integer division, so integer division rounds towards zero. To still have $a=bq+r$ with $q=a/b$ and $r=a\%b$, they had to make $a\%b$ negative when one of $a$ or $b$ is negative.

Comment: Yes @JaapScherphuis , you are right , the remainder $r$ can be negative as well in your example as you said .